# tensorflow model.evaluate and model.predict very different results

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am building a simple CNN for binary image classification, and the **AUC obtained from model.evaluate() is much higher than AUC obtained from model.predict() + roc_auc_score()**.

The whole notebook is [here](https://github.com/pro100olga/dlaicourse/blob/master/evaluate_predict.ipynb).

**Compiling model and output for model.fit():**

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001),
              metrics=['AUC'])

history = model.fit(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=8,  
      epochs=5,
      verbose=1)
```

Epoch 1/5
8/8 [==============================] - 21s 3s/step - loss: 6.7315 - auc: 0.5143

Epoch 2/5
8/8 [==============================] - 15s 2s/step - loss: 0.6626 - auc: 0.6983

Epoch 3/5
8/8 [==============================] - 18s 2s/step - loss: 0.4296 - auc: 0.8777

Epoch 4/5
8/8 [==============================] - 14s 2s/step - loss: 0.2330 - auc: 0.9606

Epoch 5/5
8/8 [==============================] - 18s 2s/step - loss: 0.1985 - auc: 0.9767

**Then model.evaluate() gives something similar:**

```
model.evaluate(train_generator)
```

9/9 [==============================] - 10s 1s/step - loss: 0.3056 - auc: 0.9956

**But then AUC calculated directly from model.predict() method is twice as lower:**

```
from sklearn import metrics

x = model.predict(train_generator)
metrics.roc_auc_score(train_generator.labels, x)
```

0.5006148007590132

---

I have read several posts on similar issues (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212021/getting-different-results-from-keras-model-evaluate-and-model-predict), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476706/what-is-the-difference-between-keras-model-evaluate-and-model-predict), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903706/keras-predict-gives-different-error-than-evaluate-loss-different-from-metrics) and also [extensive discussion on github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6977)), but they describe reasons which are irrelevant for my case:

- using binary_crossenthropy for multiclass task (not my case)
- difference between evaluate and predict due to using batch vs whole
  dataset (should not cause such drastic decline as in my case)
- using batch normalization and regularization (not my case and also should
  not cause such large decline)

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

---

**EDIT! Solution**
I have founded the solution [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3296), I just needed to call

```
train_generator.reset()
```

before model.predict and also set shuffle = False in flow_from_directory() function. The reason for difference is that generator outputs batches starting from different position, so labels and predictions will not match, because they relate to different objects. So the problem is not with evaluate or predict methods, but with generator.

---

**EDIT 2**
Using train_generator.reset() is not convenient if generator is created using flow_from_directory(), because it requires setting shuffle = False in flow_from_directory, but this will create batches containing single class during training, which affects learning. So I ended up with redefining train_generator before running predict.

Comment: when you evaluate or predict a model, cannot use the training set.  this set should be some images that were not used in training.  i had the same problem where evaluate() and predict() gave very disparate numbers where predict() was way lower.

Comment: You must actually respond with your own solution to mark it as solved. That way the question will not remain open.

Answer (score 1):

`tensorflow.keras` AUC computes the approximate AUC (Area under the curve) via a Riemann sum, which is not the same implementation as scikit-learn.

If you want to find the AUC with `tensorflow.keras`, try:

```
import tensorflow as tf

m = tf.keras.metrics.AUC()

m.update_state(train_generator.labels, x) # assuming both have shape (N,)

r = m.result().numpy()

print(r)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately, this did not help - the result, obtained with your solution, is very similar to model.predict and also much lower than model.evaluate (see [here](https://github.com/pro100olga/dlaicourse/blob/master/evaluate_predict.ipynb) in the end of file). I also think that differences in calculations in different implementations may cause minor differences, but not 0.9 vs 0.5.

Comment: can you add the shapes of train_generator.labels and x? also first few values?

Comment: sure, please see [here](https://github.com/pro100olga/dlaicourse/blob/master/evaluate_predict.ipynb) (again in the end of the file)